# jQuery Plugin Boilerplate

Tags: jquery, methods, boilerplate

i'm using the jquery boilerplate () and am having trouble accessing my options thru my differents methods.

For example

```
Plugin.prototype = {
    init: function()
    {
        console.log(this.options); // This output my options

        $(this.element).on('mouseenter', this.enter);
        $(this.element).on('mouseleave', this.leave);
        $(this.element).on('click', this.click);
    },
    enter: function(e)
    {
        console.log(this.options); // This output 'undefined'
    }
}
```

I'm trying to have access to my options in my enter method but without success.

Can someone help me figured out why?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` in the handler is the element you clicked on.

If you want to preserve your original `this`, call [jQuery.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/).

Comment: Could someone give an example of how to use JQuery Proxy within the Boilerplate. I've consulted the JQuery docs but having trouble applying it to this pattern.

Thanks

Comment: @JamesHowell: What don't you understand?